# Intterupts - context-switcht to stack or PCB

Tags: stack, cpu-registers, context-switch

I found this link describing interrupts and how a CPU manages them.

http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2874/en/

I remember from my studies in computer-science that when an interrupt occurrs the cpu saves whats in its registers and stores that in a PCB (process controll block) that belongs to the actual process.

But in this article one can read the following:

*An interrupt is a special input to the processor. When the processor is signalled that an interrupt has occurred, the processor finishes the instruction currently being executed and saves the instruction pointer and a status word to the stack. The stack is a special block of memory used to keep track of information during function calls and interrupts. The processor uses a special register called the stack pointer to keep track of the location of the top of the stack, which is where the last item was added to the stack.*

So here the context seem to be saved to the stack instead, not the PCB.

So - whats the answer to this? Does it just differs between different systems and architectures?

*(before downwoting or closing this question - give me a chance to migrate the question to another forum. I choosed stackoverflow since others seem to miss appropriate tags for the question)*

Answer (score 0):

Though it is dependent on the type of OS/processor(architecture), the design/mechanism is somewhat similar.

Generally, PCB (Process Control Block) is a data structure that has data to keep track of a process. It will have info such as the state of the process, program counter, priority, fd list and CPU register info like process status word, stack and frame pointers etc. Note that these *PCBs can be stored in stack in kernel memory*. Whenever there is a process switching to be done by scheduler, the PCB of the 1st process shall be saved(suspending the execution of 1st process) and it will load the PCB(especially PC) & context of the 2nd process, thereby it shall continue with execution of 2nd process. (That is, during context switch, the kernel stops execution of running process , copies the values in CPU registers to PCB and updates the CPU registers with values of PCB of new process that shall be scheduled.)

Mostly, when the processor is signalled that an interrupt has occurred, the hardware does a part of the context switch by saving the instruction pointer(PC) and related registers(here it is status word), stack pointer to stack which is somewhat equivalent to the contents of PCB. After kernel services(handles) the interrupt in the context established, it will load the PCB equivalent contents(especially the PC) & restore context that was in place before interrupt occurrence and will resume execution.